# What does rg mean in a member variable named m_rgNames?

Tags: c++, c

I found the member variable name of m_rgNames in some source code. According to the naming convention, such as m_iNumber typed as int, rg could represent a type name.  If this is case, what type did rg represent? Or else what's the meaning of rg in this variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for **array or range**. The author uses the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Comment: I would precise that it is the (crappy, imo) `System Hungarian Notation`, the `Apps Hungarian Notation` as originally designed by *Charles Simonyi* was much better (I think)... even though it's mostly useless with strong typing!

Answer (score 2):

It's usually short for **range**, which means the variable is a list/array